# Adding a watermark image in scrarticle documentclass

Tags: watermark

Can anyone help me with placing a watermark image (here called "OrgLOGO") in a certificate I am trying to make in latex?

```
\documentclass[16pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape,setspace,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{tgschola}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{pgothic}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\hyphenpenalty 100000

%=============================
%\input Zallman.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{Garamond}{xl}{n}}
%=============================
\usepackage{datatool}

%=============================
\def\signature#1#2{\parbox[b]{1in}{\smash{#1}\vskip12pt}
\hfill \parbox[t]{2.8in}{\shortstack{\vrule width 2.8in height 0.4pt\\\small#2}}}
\def\sigskip{\vskip0.4in plus 0.1in}
        \def\beginskip{\vskip0.5875in plus 0.1in}
%=============================
\definecolor{title}{RGB}{180,0,0}
\definecolor{other}{RGB}{171,0,255}
\definecolor{name}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\definecolor{phd}{RGB}{0,0,240}
%=============================
\usepackage{draftwatermark, graphicx}
\SetWatermarkText{\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{OrgLOGO}}
%--------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\linespread{2}\selectfont
\pagestyle{empty}
%\TileWallPaper{1\paperwidth}{1\paperheight}{border-2.jpg}
%=============================

%=============================
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[l]{1.5in}
 \includegraphics[width=.72\linewidth]{}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
%=============================
\begin{minipage}[c]{6.5in}
{\centering
{\onehalfspacing
    {\LARGE\bfseries {\color{black}{{\calligra Certificate Title}}}}\\%\initfamily
    {\calligra Address} -- {\calligra Address\\}
    \vskip0.4em
    {\large \calligra Certificate of Participation  \\}
    {\Large\bfseries\color{phd}{}}}\\
    \par}

\end{minipage}
\hfill
%=============================
\begin{minipage}[r]{1.5in}
\includegraphics[width=.92\linewidth]{}
\end{minipage}
\vskip1em
%=============================
\begin{minipage}[l]{1.5in}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{6.5in}
{\centering
{\onehalfspacing
    {\Large\bfseries \calligra \color{black}{Role played}}\par
    \vskip0.5em
    
    \par}}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[r]{1.5in}
\end{minipage}
\vskip1.8em

{\doublespacing 
This is to certify that 


\noindent
%\beginskip
{\singlespacing
\vfil
\begin{minipage}[l]{2.8in}
 \sigskip \signature{}{Certifier 1 }
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{2.8in}
\sigskip \signature{}{Certifier 2 }
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[r]{2.8in}
\sigskip \signature{}{ }
\end{minipage}}
%=============================
\pagebreak
}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including

```
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\backgroundsetup{contents=\includegraphics{image.png}, scale=0.75, angle=90, opacity=0.15}
```

in the preamble gives the desired output when compiled with pdfLatex. One can change the scale, angle and opacity to edit the image in the PDF.